# The difference between android:name and android :authorities

Tags: android-contentprovider

I'm a novice to Android, I'm confuse with the difference of how to name my android name and android authorities since the name of my package is "com.example.medicineprovider"

```
  <provider
        android:name="com.example.medicineprovider"
        android:authorities="com.example.provide.medicineprovider"
        android:readPermission="com.example.medicineprovider.READ"
        android:writePermission="com.example.medicineprovider.WRITE"
        android:exported="true"
```

/>

Answer (score 0):

the name and authority above correct

```
android:name="com.example.medicineprovider"
```

used to indicate subclass that implements ContentProvider

```
android:authorities="com.example.provide.medicineprovider"
```

The Android system stores references to content providers according to an authority ,this attribute"android:authorities" refer to ContentProvider Interface 
it may include bath ,name:attribute dont 
[Full Description here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/provider-element.html)